# htaccess redirect to non https if requested uri has xxxx.php

Tags: .htaccess

I attempted to use the following:

```
# any https link with product_info.php in it >> the http link
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^product_info\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But, URI's with that filename in the link are not redirecting to http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `^` qualifier in the regex matching the request uri. You can also get rid of the second condition and combine it with the rule:

```
# any https link with product_info.php in it >> the http link
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule product_info\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to vote you up. But, I don't have the reputation yet to do that.

Comment: Jon Lin, http://www.cheerbowsetc.com/product_info.php?cPath=1_40&products_id=2978 developer still reports infinite redirect using that code. I've commented out for now. Any possible reasons?

Comment: @DenverProphitJr. going to guess that you have code that forces HTTPS somewhere, that code needs to **exclude** `product_info.php` URI's